# Pendulum constrained by a spring and generalized forces

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, constrained-dynamics, degrees-of-freedom

I've been going through some problem sets used in a classical mechanics course offered a few semesters ago as a way to prepare for when I have to take that course next semester and I've hit a snag with one of the questions.

[image: The aforementioned problem]

I will try to describe the setup as accurately as possible.
We have a pendulum of length $2a$ with a bob of mass $m$. Lets say the pendulum is pivoted at point $A$. A distance $a$ above $A$ is another pivot $B$. Attached to $B$ is one end of a spring of free length $l(l < 2a)$ and spring constant $k$, while the other end of the spring is attached to a point on the string of the pendulum. We have to find the equations of motion.
Being fairly new (read beginner) to using the Lagrangian and generalized forces, I am not able to figure out the following:

**a) What are the constraints for the system and whether they are holonomic or non-holonomic.

b) The number of degrees of freedom 

c) The expressions for the generalized forces 

d) And finally, the equations of motion for the bob.**

**Edit**: Progress I've made (Assuming the motion is restricted to the plane of the screen): Unconstrained, the mass would have 2 degrees of freedom. When I make a pendulum out of it however, we put a constraint on it
$$
\sqrt{x^2 + y^2} = 2a
$$
Where origin is set at pivot $A$, and $(x,y)$ are the co-ordinates of the bob. <\br>

This leads to one generalized co-ordinate, $\theta$, the angle the pendulum makes with the vertical. <\br>
I can also write the Kinetic Energy of the pendulum mass,
$$
T = \frac{1}{2}m(\dot x^2 + \dot y^2)
$$
And the potential due to the force of gravity with pivot $A$ as reference point for $V = 0$,
$$
V = -mg(y)
$$
I can make the substitutions $x = 2a\sin\theta$ and $y = 2a\cos\theta$ in these expressions. Unfortunately, this is where I'm stuck. I cannot figure out what the spring does to this system, nor can I figure out how to include that in my equations. Does it even effect the degrees of freedom?

Comment: Hi Tushnim Yuvaraj. Welcome to Phys.SE. I removed your last question, as Phys.SE prefers 1 question per post.